# GetRequestStream - writing to output

Tags: c#, compact-framework, http-post

How would I write the raw HTTP post to the console window? I am using the compact framework 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to debug client-server communication over HTTP, there is a more convenient way then writing to a console, you can use Fiddler.